# My question is about getting error mesage while starting my laptop on dual boot ( windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04.3)

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, bios, firmware, sgx

i do have dual boot on my laptop Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.3. I am getting this message on my laptop's display. Can you guys please explain me what wrong on my laptop and how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does it still boot up ok?

Comment: You say 20.04.3, but kernel 6.5? If using newer 22.04.3 kernel should be 6.5 but with 22.04.3 you also have newer drivers? How new is system, what brand/model? Have you updated firmware for UEFI and if SSD its firmware?

Comment: If you're using 20.04.3 you're years behind on applying security fixes (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded **before** that date, so you've not applied upgrades for two years??)  but 6.5 kernel implies as @oldfred said that your details are incorrect and you're not using the Ubuntu 2020-April release.  If you're using 20.04.3 as stated; your system is using *revoked* keys & thus secure-boot won't be possible until you upgrade to newer keys... but I doubt you're using 20.04 as you state.

Comment: You can confirm your version using command: `lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 1):

### Known Issue

There is a bug report on this issue:

- [UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds complaints in newer kernels](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubsan-array-index-out-of-bounds-complaints-in-newer-kernels/271705/5)

---

### No serious consequences reported

However, according to a comment on the link, ii appears the message doesn't effect operation:

> I should note that this warning is harmless. It’s due to the wrong size being declared on some arrays in UVM. You can see it in the code here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/blob/main/kernel-open/nvidia-uvm/uvm_pmm_gpu.c#L224 135
>
> These are C “flexible array members” and should just be declared with no size.